# Applying symbolic determinant in Matlab to an abstract class

Tags: oop, matlab, matrix, determinants

I have implemented a class in Matlab, which overloads the '+', '-' and '*' operator. Now I am interested in calculating the determinant of a Matrix whose entries consist of instances of this class. Is there a lazy way to use the symbolic determinant function of Matlab for doing this or do I have to implement a determinant Algorithm myself?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function in your class called **det**.
If you are using Matlab OOP by using arrays, and not cell arrays, you can call det(M) on a matrix of your instances.

```
class MyClass
     methods(Access=public)
          function d = det(this)
               M = zeros(size(this));
               for i=1:size(this,1)
                    for j=1:size(this,2)
                         % M(i,j) = %TODO -> convert by your own logic
                    end
               end
               d = det(M);
          end
     end
end
```

Comment: This one would work if my object would be convertible in a number. This however is not the case. I'm interested in a general determinant function, which might return something different then a number (a polynomial for example if the matrix entries are polynomials).

Comment: @Igor, Did you try to use the symbolic toolbox?

Comment: Yes. I am interested in linking the determinant function from the symbolic toolbox to my object.